# linking an item in table using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to figure out how to link items in a row of a table while keeping the row in place, I have the following code:

```
echo "<br><br><table border=0 cellpadding=3>";
echo "<td><b>Player Name</b></td>";
echo "<td><b>Position</b></td>";
echo "<td><b>Height</b></td>";
echo "<td><b>Weight</b></td>";
echo "<td><b>Birthdate</b></td>"; 
echo "<td><b>NHL Rights</b></td>";
echo "<td><b>CNGHL Team</b></td>";
echo "<td><b>Current Team</b></td>";
echo "<td><b>Current League</b></td>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($oteaminfo)) 
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".$row['FullName']."</td> ";
echo "<td>".$row['Position']."</td> ";
echo "<td>".$row['Height']."</td> ";
echo "<td>".$row['Weight']."</td> ";
echo "<td>".$row['DOB']."</td> ";
echo "<td>".$row['Team']."</td> ";
echo "<td>".$row['CNGHLRights']."</td> ";
echo "<td>".$row['InternationalTeam']."</td> ";
echo "<td>".$row['InternationLeague']."</td> ";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

I have tried using

```
     echo "<a href=\"cnghlplayers.php?  PlayerID=".$row['PlayerID']."\">".$row['FullName']."<br>";
```

In Place of the

```
      echo "<td>".$row['FullName']."</td> ";
```

In the table but It puts the links into a new row above my current table. Any help would be greatly appreciated, I tried searching for this topic but I couldn't find any information that was helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap the `<td>` element around:

```
echo '<td><a href="cnghlplayers.php?PlayerID='.$row['PlayerID'].'">'.$row['FullName'].'</a></td>';
```

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick it worked really well for getting the links to show up.

Comment: @BrianJKirk Glad it helped. Please make sure to accept it as the correct answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your link with TD:

```
echo "<td><a href=\"cnghlplayers.php?  PlayerID=".$row['PlayerID']."\">".$row['FullName']."</a></td>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Test this, there were some issues with your table markup. This should be a bit easier to read as well.

```
?> <!-- this line ends your php code so that you can format the HTML sanely -->
<br />
<br />
<table border=0 cellpadding=3>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Player Name</b></td>
            <td><b>Position</b></td>
            <td><b>Height</b></td>
            <td><b>Weight</b></td>
            <td><b>Birthdate</b></td> 
            <td><b>NHL Rights</b></td>
            <td><b>CNGHL Team</b></td>
            <td><b>Current Team</b></td>
            <td><b>Current League</b></td>
        </tr>

    <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($oteaminfo)) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo "<a href='cnghlplayers.php?PlayerID=".$row['PlayerID'].">".$row['FullName']."</a>"; ?></td> 
            <td><?php echo $row['Position']; ?></td> 
            <td><?php echo $row['Height']; ?></td> 
            <td><?php echo $row['Weight']; ?></td> 
            <td><?php echo $row['DOB']; ?></td> 
            <td><?php echo $row['Team']; ?></td> 
            <td><?php echo $row['CNGHLRights']; ?></td> 
            <td><?php echo $row['InternationalTeam']; ?></td> 
            <td><?php echo $row['InternationLeague']; ?></td> 
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    </table>
<?php //continues your php code below
```

Comment: So where are the links?

Comment: @TobiasKun I have added a link in there for you. See what that does and let me know if you have any questions on how to implement the rest or if that even is working for you.

Comment: I don't want to implement anything. I just tried to show you, that you do not answered the question of Brian. :)

Comment: @TobiasKun Oh I didn't look at the name and thought you were the asker. I figured what I had provided before was enough to get the Ahah! Moment going for Brian and he could figure it out from there. I can always take another look at the answer to improve it.